# How do I get an img click to execute js using jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I need an image click to execute a js function. I have it working in my project, but I have other code to develop so I'm trying to use jsfiddle. But I can't get this simple code to work in jsfiddle. when I use jsfiddle and I click the image, nothing happens.

What am I missing in my efforts to use jsfiddle?

My HTML

```
<div>
<img id="additem" Title="Add Item" onclick="myfunc()" OnMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer';" OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor='default';" src="~/images/Sign_Add_Icon_32.png" />
</div>
```

My JS

```
function myfunc() {
alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the fiddle then ?

Comment: Good question. The best answer I have is that I just started with jsfiddle and don't know how. Let me try this. http://jsfiddle.net/lgavitt/RxrDZ/

Comment: You don't know how to add a link to the fiddle in your question ?

Comment: @Sachin You did what my answer says

Comment: @Sachin Why the difference in the link you provided vs the one I provided. Is it that simple in referencing a jsfiddle to simply remove your username? It seemed to work for mine, but that just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onload` in framework and extensions, set it to `in head` or `in body`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f2yJz/)**

### This works!  But what was the problem?

You can't wait for the document to load in that case, because `myfunc` isn't defined before the Javascript is executed *after* the HTML loads.

Comment: Excellent. That solved the problem. Many thanks. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.